# MVC Checkfor / Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

Im having some trouble adding bootstrap styling to `CheckBoxFor` and `LabelFor` in mvc. Its rendering how I would like, but its displaying the text IsChecked. How do I remove the rendered text?

```
<div class="slider">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked, new { @class = "toggle-pill" })
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsChecked, new { @class = "toggle-label" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data annotation for that.

In .cs file, you can mention the Display attribute for property

```cs
[Display(Name = "Text for Checkbox")]
public bool IsChecked{ get; set; }
```

Keep your html as it is

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked, new { @class = "toggle-pill" })
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsChecked, new { @class = "toggle-label" })
```

This will give you a checkbox along with 'Text for Checkbox'